# enabledelayedexpansion concat string every time come in block batch script

Tags: arrays, batch-file, smtp, string-concatenation

I have below code which print(else code) error in command prompt when control come into it.But I want a string which contains all error in one string (Concat previous Strings), and use that string to send mail.

```
  @echo off
echo Working !!!
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type test.log ^| findstr "Queue_ID"') do (
   set $Line=%%a
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=^=," %%b in ('echo !$Line!') do (
      set $Value=%%b
      set $Value=#Queue_id!$Value: =!
      if not defined !$Value! (set !$Value!=1) else (echo Error with [!$Value!]) 
))
endlocal
echo Done !!!
Pause
```

and mail sending code is

```
S:\blat.exe -body " error_String came from else code" -subject "KSD Error" -tf %recipients% -server %smtpserver% -f %sender%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will send an E-mail ONLY if there is some error :

```
  @echo off
echo Working !!!
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type test.log ^| findstr "Queue_ID"') do (
   set $Line=%%a
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=^=," %%b in ('echo !$Line!') do (
      set $Value=%%b
      set $Value=#Queue_id!$Value: =!
      if not defined !$Value! (set !$Value!=1) else (set $liste=!$Liste!,[!$Value!]) 
))

if defined $Liste (
  echo Error List : !$Liste!
  echo sending Mail...
  S:\blat.exe -body !$Liste! -subject "KSD Error" -tf %recipients% -server %smtpserver% -f %sender%)
endlocal
echo Done !!!
Pause
```

Comment: hi SachaDee!your code is working very fine, but now I recognized a problem I scheduled this code in every 1/2 Hour so this code keep sending mail after every scan of duplicate Queue_Id in log file while I need it like for every duplicate Queue_Id it send only one mail

Comment: you are getting any problem on understanding the above issue ? Please let me know. 
Please help me on this also.

Comment: Hi @user3856852 ! My code scan the `.LOG` file and when finished, if a `Queue_ID` is found it send a mail. I'm not sure to understand your problem...

Comment: This script when finish, send mail if found same Queue_ID multiple times. I have to run this script in every hour so I needed if in previous log scan it has send mail for some Queue_ID then in next log scan, it will not send mail for that previous Queue_ID means if found new Queue_ID multiple times then only send mail.

Comment: I have an idea for this may be help  ... In every time log scan we can write multiple Queue_ID in a text file and during next scan we search also for text file's Queue_ID and ignore them if found . Log file created daily with cutternt date(Ex. 20140821.LOG) . so we have to overwrite this text file when next day first time script will run

Comment: Please SachaDee look into this, if you need more information let me know